# Doctrine delete from QueryBuidler with cascade

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, cascade

I got two entities linked by a ManyToOne relation.
Let's call them `Parent` and `Child` ; a Parent can have multiple Childs.

I defined a `cascade={"persist", "remove"}` on the relation. It seems to work while I'm using the `$em->remove($parent);` method.

But the fact is that I have to remove a lot of Parents at one time (more than 3,000 for example). In order to do such a bulk delete, Doctrine recommend to use the `delete` method directly from the QueryBuidler :

```
#ParentRepository
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->delete();
$qb->getQUery()->execute();
```

But when I try that, I got the following error : 
`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails [...]`

It seems that the remove cascade is not followed while using delete().

Any help on that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the option `onDelete="SET NULL"` in the annotation of your entity `Child`. Example:

```
class Parent {
/**
*@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Child", mappedBy="parent")
*/
protected $childs;
}

class Child {
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Parent", inversedBy="childs")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
*/
protected $parent;
}
```